# Service Bus Message Broker SharePoint 2013 High CPU and Memory

Tags: designer-workflow, service

I am testing to deploy new list workflow 2013 so I run a powershell script to restart the workflow in list (around 50 items). then, it is stuck.
And checked the service with Service Bus Message Broker that is High CPU and Memory. 
Any ideas for it. Thank you very much.

Comment: is the workflow manager on the dedicated server or installed on the SharePoint server? whats the topology?

Comment: Can you share your PS that you use to restart the WF?

Comment: my scripts like this : https://prairiedeveloper.com/2017/02/start-sharepoint-2013-workflows-with-powershell/